# AWS Elasticsearch Sizing

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

After performing some analysis & capacity calculations regarding storage requirements for a Highly Available AWS Managed Elasticsearch cluster I came up with the following:

1. Three separate Indexes (each represent specific logging data from different parts of the Platform).
2. Retention period of 14 days
3. The three indexes for a total of 14 days would require 12GB, 12GB and 25GB.
4. As each index is below 30GB for this retention period, I'm assuming a single Shard is required.
5. Queries and aggregation will be performed against the full 14 day period.
6. The ES cluster will be primarily write heavy, with reads only performed by operational staff that require logs for diagnosis purposes.

The following guide from AWS includes a table at the bottom that provides indicative sizings for an ES cluster based on different factors. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-t-shirt-size-your-domain/

The X-Small option which assumes a daily ingest of 10GB, matches my calculations in terms of storage and advises a 3-master node & 2-data node cluster. The data nodes as recommended have 2 v-CPU and 8GB RAM.

- Would this configuration be suitable based on my requirements above? I'm concerned regarding the amount of CPUs in the data nodes and the fact that aggregation will be performed against the full 14 days.
- If I am deploying in AWS Canada which has 2 Availability Zones, a 3-Master node setup can result in downtime if the AZ that is impacted from Service loss has two of the nodes in that AZ. There's essentially a 50% chance of downtime. Is there any benefit to running this 3-master node set-up in an AWS Region that has only 2 AZs?

I understand that the initial configuration that will be provisioned will need to be constantly monitored and then potentially adjusted in terms of scale, however it would be great to know if my estimations are realistic or not.

Thanks,
James.

Comment: The configuration seems fine to your needs, but it also depends on the size of your documents, how many fields they have and the mapping of the documents.

With only 2 AZs the chances of downtime are the same using 3 Master Nodes or just 1 Master Node, I don't see any benefit in running 3 Master Nodes with only 2 AZs.